# Android : Facebook V2.5 email error

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get a email id from Facebook SDK but not getting it.
I made a key from Facebook Developer page using version 2.5. Is there any further permission required to give from user side or from code?

```html
 loginButton.setReadPermissions("user_friends", "user_photos", "regEmail",
                "user_birthday", "public_profile");
```

Earlier i was able to get it with old SDK, but no idea about new SDK changes

Comment: can you show us the exact error you get?

Comment: in facebook response i get name and social id bit email id not in response of facebook

Comment: sounds more like a problem you should contact facebook with!